# Warning: Unable to Access

Tags: git, macos, terminal, permission-denied

Im using the MacOS, im the terminal and i keep getting

warning: unable to access '/Users/user/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

As im continuing to enter commands, it will show a warning or fatal but then it will complete what im already trying to do?

Users-MacBook-Pro:coursera-test user$ git push

Username for 'https://github.com': DestinyPratt

Password for 'https://DestinyPratt@github.com':

warning: unable to access '/Users/user/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied

Enumerating objects: 5, done.

Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.

Delta compression using up to 2 threads

Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.

Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 441 bytes | 441.00 KiB/s, done.

Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

To https://github.com/DestinyPratt/coursera-test.git

2543b70..b0d49ad  gh-pages -> gh-pages

Comment: Yes. Refer this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320682/ownership-of-the-config-folder-in-home-directory

Comment: i entered in the command with my username it said No such file or directory

Comment: @Des Were you in your home directory (/Users/user) when you ran it? The command in that answer assumes you are. Here's a version that should work wherever you happen to be: `sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/.config`